# pass a string to grailsApplication.config in service layer

Tags: grails, properties

Can anyone know how to pass the string as a parameter to  grailsApplication.config.

```
 I have tried the following.

class ConfigPropertiesLoader {
   def grailsApplication

   def getProperty(String property ){
           def properties=grailsApplication.config.${property}

    return properties;
}
```

This is the error i got,

```
   Error 2013-02-13 12:59:29,850 [http-bio-8080-exec-10] ERROR 0].[grails]  -    Servlet.service() for servlet grails threw exception
   Message: Cannot get property 'config' on null object
   Line | Method
   ->>   30 | getProperty      in    com.nagra.ms.sam.config.ConfigPropertiesLoader$$ENxJABt5

   |     51 | <init>           in com.nagra.ms.sam.entity.account.controller.AccountController
   |    196 | getBean . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
   |    842 | lookupController in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
   |    176 | doFilter . . . . in     ''
   |     63 | doFilter         in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
   |   1110 | runWorker . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
   |    603 | run              in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
   ^    722 | run . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: if my answer worked for you. I'd love to have it accepted ;)

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure I understand your exact question so I am going to list a couple different scenarios for you with solution:

Consider the following two entries in Config.groovy

```
feedbackAddress="xyz@abcdefg.com"

blogs = {groupName->
        if(groupName == 'IT') {
            //return blog URLs for IT folks
        } else if(groupName == 'UX') {
            //return blog URLs for UX folks
        } else {
            //return others
        }
    }
```

Case 1: Using a String as the config name. You can access the feedbackAddress like:

```
def feedbackAddress = grailsApplication.config["feedbackAddress"]
```

Case 2: Passing a paramater to a config. You can list the blogs for specific group like:

```
def groupName = "IT"
grailsApplication.config.blogs(groupName) //this will give you whatever's defined in the IT block of config.
```

Hope this helps..